# distcc and arm cross compile

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling, distcc

im trying to setup a small 2 system distcc compile cluster for a new project im working on but for some reason i cant get the second server in the cluster to compile.

the arm-eabi-gcc file works if i try to run it on said server i get the normal no input files error but distcc has other ideas.

extract from its log file :

```
distccd[13005] (dcc_execvp) ERROR: failed to exec arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
distccd[13002] (dcc_job_summary) client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32890 COMPILE_ERROR exit:110 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:1103ms arm-eabi-gcc arch/arm/vfp/vfpdouble.c
distccd[13003] (dcc_pump_readwrite) ERROR: unexpected eof on fd5
distccd[13003] (dcc_job_summary) client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32891 CLI_DISCONN exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:107 time:429ms
distccd[12998] (dcc_pump_readwrite) ERROR: unexpected eof on fd5
distccd[12998] (dcc_job_summary) client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32888 CLI_DISCONN exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:107 time:2499ms
distccd[13001] (dcc_pump_readwrite) ERROR: unexpected eof on fd5
distccd[13001] (dcc_job_summary) client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32889 CLI_DISCONN exit:0 sig:0 core:0 ret:107 time:2512ms
```

any ideas what is going on?

edit: i can compile for x86 and x86_64 quite happily using distcc just not arm for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The cross compiler must

- (a) be installed (exactly the same binary, not just the same name/location)
- (b) in the search path for distcc

Depending on your system setup (distcc as a daemon, or under inetd) the easiest way to achieve things might be to symlink the binaries into /usr/local/bin for the distcc hosts.

Comment: ive got all the symlinks etc made i think, and the binary itself works if i run it locally on the problem server, just distcc cant execute it

Comment: What distro are you using? I found this [nice gentoo page](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/cross-compiling-distcc.xml)